# is it correct to say "Pull your forearms down at a right angle with your upper arms"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

I saw this sentence in [Oxford dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/right-angle)

**Place the table at right angles/at a right angle to the wall**

I am sure if it means the table is in contact  with the wall lengthways or widthways or not.

It could fall into one of these 4 options:

[image]

Now, I am teaching my daughter to swim breaststroke. I want to express that when she pulls down her arms, her forearms should be at a 90 degree angle with her upper arms.

[image]

is it correct or natural to say "**Pull your forearms down at a right angle with your upper arms**"?

Comment: Since all four corners of a table are right angles, the meaning isn't very clear, but presumably it refers to a long table placed in either position on the left of your drawing.

Comment: ...and I would probably say "Bend your elbows at right angles"!

Comment: As with all "is this ok" questions, to be on topic, you must edit to say *why* you have concerns about this usage. Right now the only answer is "Sure, it's fine," which is not a very useful answer. Voting to close, and downvoting.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it asks "is this correct," without discussing any reason that it might not be. This gives it the same problems as a proofreading question.

Comment: **Show** don't tell.

Comment: I wonder whether you understand the concept of a right angle. The diagrams in which the long side of the table touches the wall are not reasonable interpretations of this sentence. If the table were square, we would not know what to do. But the wall is a long line, and the table, as a rectangle, is a "fat line." Read more about right angles if necessary.

Comment: Place the table *perpendicular* to the wall.

Comment: Isn't this the "butterfly" stroke?

Comment: "Pull your forearms down at a right angle with your upper arms" is anatomically impossible. You could hold them forwards or up at such an angle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We wouldn't say "pull your forearms down at a right angle" as that implies that the pulling motion itself is at a right angle relative to something.

More like this:

> When pulling your arms down, keep them bent at the elbow at a right angle.